# Powershell - Beginner Advice for looping through an array

Tags: powershell

I'm using Powershell to do some high-level automation and I'd like to loop through an array of 2 values in a dropdown list on a website...no idea how how to implement it.

Here's the code:

```
        $Array =  "FirstItem", "SecondItem"

        Foreach ($i in $Array)

         {
    while($ie.busy) {sleep 1} 
            $doc = $ie.document
            $ie.document.getElementById("DropDownListBtn").click()
            $link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | where-object {$_.innerText -eq '$i'}
        # Note: without using the variable above, I would expect the statement would look like this:
                # $link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | where-object {$_.innerText -eq 'FirstItem'}
            $link.click()
        }
```

Here's the error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:9 char:28

+                 $link.click <<<< ()

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (click:String) [], RuntimeException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: What is your actual question here? Does the code produce undesired/unexpected results? Do you get an error?

Comment: Sorry...yes, i get an error:                                      You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:9 char:28
+                 $link.click <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (click:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:9 char:28
+                 $link.click <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (click:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error information there. As you can see it becomes unreadable in a comment.

Comment: the error basically tells you what is wrong, `$link` is null. run `$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') |
              where-object {$_.innerText -eq '$i'}` on its own and see what it returns (if anything

Answer (score 0):

You need some error handling / checking.

I'd start by adding error handling to your $ie and $link instantiation code, e.g.:

```
$ie = <code to create object> -erroraction silentlycontinue;
if ( $? ) {
    # All ok - proceed
} else {
    # it failed
}
```

...or, use try...catch, but this doesn't always work, as not all PowerShell calls raise exceptions.

```
try {
    $ie =  <code to create object> -erroraction silentlycontinue;
    }
catch [Exception] {
    # it failed
    }
```

Comment: the -erroraction parameter only works on cmdlets not on object method calls like the one the op uses

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  I troubleshooted further and realized that I needed to remove the single quotes around $i:

```
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | where-object {$_.innerText -eq $i}
```